# Loading a web site to IIS

Tags: iis

A developer just send me a running website files from IIS directory. I want to know if I can run the website on my PC. The file contain "Default.aspx" file, which I assume is of some importance.

I want to know if it is possible to run the website on my PC, I have installed IIS and I placed the file in the wwwroot folder, but unfortunately I dont know how to proceed from here.

Can someone please point me to the right way to continue with this task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably, you have more than just the file you mention?

Comment: ofcourse there are a whole bunch of files

Answer (score 1):

### First time use of IIS

Now that IIS is running on your system, it should have defaulted to running on port 80. You can test this out by going to http://localhost/

The file you have placed in the wwwroot directory `Default.aspx` is an ASP.NET application. You need to go to IIS and convert the directory it is stored into a web application.

Now when creating web applications, it is better to create them in another folder other than your wwwroot folder, and in the case of this tutorial it is easier. Move your `Default.aspx` into a folder named 'webapp', or something of the like.

> To convert it into an application, do the following:

1. In the Server Manager, expand the
   'Roles' item in the tree
2. Expand the 'Web Server (IIS)' item
3. Click on 'Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
4. In the window on the right hand side, you will need to open up your server. In my case, my server is called WIN2008R2. Your server name will be located inside the 'Connections' pane. Expand your server in the tree
5. Expand the 'Sites' item
6. Expand your newly created site. There should only be one there, and the item will have a globe next to it
7. Now right click on your 'webapp' item which will have a folder next to it, and click 'Convert to Application'. Then leave all the properties the same in the window that comes up and click OK.

You have now created a new web application. By going to http://localhost/webapp you should see it working.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr.Kennedy

What is the "Server Manager" you mentioned in step 1?

Comment: Not a problem. The server manager is a control panel which you get on Windows Server operating systems. If you do not have a server operating system such as Windows Server 2008, you can use the 'Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager' by going to the your control panel, then click Administrative Tools, and then open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. This is how you do it on Windows 7 (what my computer is using).

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure IIS to host an ASP.NET website.

You can find information about configuring IIS here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx

Another option is using the Cassini web server (instead of IIS). You may find it easier to configure: http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/